# Packet installation with pip

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, repository

I have an offline repository for python. When I try to install a package from PyCharm terminal , I get an error.

```
pip install http://IP_Adress/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64 Selenium
```

The error is:

```
    (venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>pip install http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64 Selenium
Collecting http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  Downloading http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
     - 3.5 MB 5.0 MB/s
  ERROR: Cannot unpack file C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-unpack-_b5zun_c\win-64 (downloaded from C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-aechvlnx, content-type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1); cannot
 detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-aechvlnx
```

Offline repository has only tar.bz files. I thought this may be the problem and tried to extract the selenium packet from tar.bz.

```
tar -xvf Selenium-3.9.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
```

This command extracts 2 directories which are **info** and **Lib**. I didn't understand which directory should I give to pip in order to install, so I wrote both directories. Again I got errors.

```
(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>pip install http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/extracted_files Selenium
Collecting http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/extracted_files
  Downloading http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/extracted_files (1.5 kB)
  ERROR: Cannot unpack file C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-unpack-pyjq7zca\extracted_files (downloaded from C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-p1p94wxu, content-type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
); cannot detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-p1p94wxu

(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>pip install http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/extracted_files/info Selenium
Collecting http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/extracted_files/info
  Downloading http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/extracted_files/info (2.8 kB)
  ERROR: Cannot unpack file C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-unpack-g49u5kfo\info (downloaded from C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-xe2_za7n, content-type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1); cannot d
etect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-xe2_za7n

(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>pip install http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/extracted_files/Lib Selenium
Collecting http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/extracted_files/Lib
  Downloading http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/extracted_files/Lib (1.1 kB)
  ERROR: Cannot unpack file C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-unpack-kvgxbu_1\Lib (downloaded from C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-orjzw289, content-type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1); cannot de
tect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-orjzw289
```

In addition I tried below commands as well which leads to errors again.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>pip install selenium
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.
HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000D513C67670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.
HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000D513C67A90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.
HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000D513C67C10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.
HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000D513C67DF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.
HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000D513C5B4F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/selenium/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium



(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>pip install --trusted-host IP_Address  http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pk
gs/main/win-64/ selenium
Collecting http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/
  Downloading http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/
     - 3.5 MB ...
  ERROR: Cannot unpack file C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-unpack-17_v5oie\win-64 (downloaded from C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-
build-h0c_a540, content-type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1); cannot detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h0c_a540



(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>pip install --trusted-host IP_Address --extra-index-url http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/rep
o.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/ selenium
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.
HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000C5BCEA9A30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.
HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000C5BCEA9BE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.
HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000C5BCEA9D90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.
HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000C5BCEA9F40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.
HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000C5BCED7130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/selenium/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium


(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>pip install --trusted-host IP_Address http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkg
s/main/win-64/ "selenium-3.9.0-py36_."
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'selenium-3.9.0-py36_.'
```

**EDIT**

I try the command below which is written in answers. It gives different behaviour. It starts to download the real package (which is 876 KB) but gives error and exit.

**Note** My client's pip version is 20.2.3

```
(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>pip install http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/selenium-3.9.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
Collecting http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/selenium-3.9.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
  Downloading http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/selenium-3.9.0-py36_0.tar.bz2 (876 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 876 kB 6.4 MB/s
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pi
p-req-build-mk5is0qr\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-req-build-mk5is0qr\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read
().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-pip-egg-info-hvvkolxv'
         cwd: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-mk5is0qr\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tokenize.py", line 392, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-req-build-mk5is0qr\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.utput.
```

Also I got the pip installation logs. They're below. It seems the 'setup.py' file or directory is missing. Should I download and put that package inside the directory? Is there a link for that package?

```
2021-01-15T09:32:20,060 Using pip 20.2.3 from c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
2021-01-15T09:32:20,076 Non-user install because user site-packages disabled
2021-01-15T09:32:20,076 Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-oyzheyaq
2021-01-15T09:32:20,076 Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-tracker-5t2tri7w
2021-01-15T09:32:20,076 Initialized build tracking at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-tracker-5t2tri7w
2021-01-15T09:32:20,076 Created build tracker: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-tracker-5t2tri7w
2021-01-15T09:32:20,076 Entered build tracker: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-tracker-5t2tri7w
2021-01-15T09:32:20,076 Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-j3apk6ad
2021-01-15T09:32:20,076 Collecting http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/selenium-3.9.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
2021-01-15T09:32:20,076   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-57fyjwkw
2021-01-15T09:32:20,076   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-unpack-i3ywdpyn
2021-01-15T09:32:20,092   Downloading http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/selenium-3.9.0-py36_0.tar.bz2 (876 kB)
2021-01-15T09:32:20,638   Added http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/selenium-3.9.0-py36_0.tar.bz2 to build tracker 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-req-tracker-5t2tri7w'
2021-01-15T09:32:20,638     Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-57fyjwkw\setup.py) egg_info for package from http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/selenium-3.9.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
2021-01-15T09:32:20,638     Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-pip-egg-info-u0ef2h8b
2021-01-15T09:32:20,638     Running command python setup.py egg_info
2021-01-15T09:32:20,888     Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-01-15T09:32:20,888       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
2021-01-15T09:32:20,888       File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tokenize.py", line 392, in open
2021-01-15T09:32:20,888         buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
2021-01-15T09:32:20,888     FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-req-build-57fyjwkw\\setup.py'
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904 Exception information:
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904 Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 228, in _main
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     status = self.run(options, args)
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     return func(self, options, args)
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 323, in run
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 183, in resolve
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 388, in _resolve_one
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 340, in _get_abstract_dist_for
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     abstract_dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 91, in _get_prepared_distribution
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 40, in prepare_distribution_metadata
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     self.req.prepare_metadata()
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 555, in prepare_metadata
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     self.metadata_directory = self._generate_metadata()
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 530, in _generate_metadata
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     return generate_metadata_legacy(
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\build\metadata_legacy.py", line 70, in generate_metadata
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     call_subprocess(
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904   File "c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\subprocess.py", line 242, in call_subprocess
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904     raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
2021-01-15T09:32:20,904 pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
2021-01-15T09:32:20,920 1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
2021-01-15T09:32:20,920 * https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
2021-01-15T09:32:20,920 Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
2021-01-15T09:32:20,920 Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
2021-01-15T09:32:20,920 Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
2021-01-15T09:32:20,920 Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000048095AD5B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')) - skipping
2021-01-15T09:32:20,920 Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'pip': discarding no candidates
2021-01-15T09:32:20,920 Removed http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/selenium-3.9.0-py36_0.tar.bz2 from build tracker 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-req-tracker-5t2tri7w'
2021-01-15T09:32:20,920 Removed build tracker: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-req-tracker-5t2tri7w'
```

Comment: The first error is most likely because the url you are trying to download is not valid url for the actual package.. Error message says that content-type was text/html so there's probably some 404 error that serves you a html file -- or the http server is configured incorrectly ..

Comment: @rasjani it cannot be an error message - it would not be 3.5 MB big !

Comment: inspect the downloaded file and see whats in there ?

Comment: @rasjani `ERROR: Cannot unpack file C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-unpack-17_v5oie\win-64`  This is pretty surely a directory, and a directory CANNOT be unpacked !

Comment: @g-baysec does /PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/ on the server or one of its parent directories contain a html file ?

Comment: @rasjani I can install selenium packages from anaconda environment. My condarc file has the exact path as pycharm. So the path and the http server configuration is true in my case.

Comment: @frederic I try to install selenium package with giving the full path and it tries to install the real package (876 KB). But It gives different error. I added the error to my post.

Comment: @G.Baysec the setup.py is a file used to set up the package and install it. The package on your webserver seems broken. Please upgrade pip `pip install pip --upgrade` and just install selenium directly. from PyPI

Comment: @frederic My pip version is 20.2.3. I also found out that older versions of pip needs that setup.py. But after 19.x it should not need that setup.py. In my case, pip still wants that setup.py. I also check the packet with 'tar -jtvf <package_name> | grep setup.py '. There is no such thing. Is there a specific pip version you know that doesn't need the setup.py? I can download and install it to my offline environment.

Comment: @G.Baysec please try `pip install selenium`. If that works, you can uninstall it again with `pip uninstall selenium` and then do `pip download --no-deps selenium` to download the package to the current working directory. Then, replace the package on the webserver with the just downloaded archive, and `pip install http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/Selenium-3.9.0-py36_0.tar.bz2` should work

Comment: @frederic Unfortunately `pip install selenium` not working because of my machine is in offline environment. Even if that method works , there are too many packages  that suffers from this 'setup.py' issue. I can't replace them all.

Comment: @G.Baysec i did some google research and it is __not__ possible to install a package not containing a setup.py file with pip. But you could download the archive from you webserver using wget or curl or something similar, extract the archive using tar and place the Selenium folder somewhere in your PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the whole path to the package (or the whole url, if its located on a server):

```
$ pip install http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/Selenium-3.9.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
```

instead of

```
$ pip install http://IP_Address/PythonRepositories/Windows/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/ Selenium
```

The errors you got are caused by pip trying to unpack a directory instead of an archive (at least i think so)

Comment: When I try your solution, it gives different behaviour. It looks like it starts to download the package (876 KB) but it gives error. I'll add the error to my post.